# NSLinguisticTagger - enumerateLinguisticTagsInRange block not limiting range

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c-blocks

I'm using `enumerateLinguisticTagsInRange` within a method like so:

```
[nonAttributedString enumerateLinguisticTagsInRange:stringRange
                                           scheme:NSLinguisticTagSchemeTokenType
                                          options:NSLinguisticTaggerOmitWhitespace | NSLinguisticTaggerOmitPunctuation | NSLinguisticTaggerJoinNames
                                      orthography:[NSOrthography orthographyWithDominantScript:@"Latn" languageMap:languageMap]
                                       usingBlock:^(NSString *tag, NSRange tokenRange, NSRange sentenceRange, BOOL *stop) {

       // If the token is a word...
       if ([tag isEqualToString:@"Word"])
       {
           // (And add to the tracking dictionary)
           NSMutableDictionary *wordAndRange = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
           [wordAndRange setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(tokenRange.location + tokenRange.length)] forKey:[nonAttributedString substringWithRange:tokenRange]];

           [typedWordsAndRanges addObject:wordAndRange];
       }
   }];
```

The tagger is working fine but it's not limiting the range to `stringRange`. It's enumerating through `nonAttributedString` in it's entirety.

If I include the following logs right above this block:

```
 NSLog(@"########### stringRange.location = %d", stringRange.location);
 NSLog(@"########### stringRange.length = %d", stringRange.length);
 NSLog(@"########### substring = %@", [nonAttributedString substringWithRange:stringRange]);
```

I get the following output:

```
2013-03-18 21:06:27.744 WEJ[13231:c07] ########### stringRange.location = 10
2013-03-18 21:06:27.745 WEJ[13231:c07] ########### stringRange.length = 4
2013-03-18 21:06:27.805 WEJ[13231:c07] ########### substring =  de
```

So `stringRange` is correct. However, it's still enumerating through `nonAttributedString` in it's entirety.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The [docs for `enumerateTagsInRange:scheme:options:usingBlock:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSLinguisticTagger_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSLinguisticTagger/enumerateTagsInRange%3ascheme%3aoptions%3ausingBlock%3a) state:

> It is important to note that this method will return the ranges of all tokens that intersect the given range.

If you want to consider only those tokens that are *completely* in `stringRange`, you'll have to retrieve that substring from `nonAttributedString` before invoking `enumerateTagsInRange::::`.